# Running zabbix on same server as Apache

Tags: zabbix

Currently I run Apache on RHEL and Zabbix on the same server. I can access the web server via example.com and zabbix via example.com:81/zabbix. I would like to be able to view zabbix using example.com/zabbix instead. How can I reconfigure Zabbix to work this way?

I was thinking of using an alias to the zabbix folder but not sure how to do that or if it would even work properly.

I have http installed as well as httpd24 from supplemental repo. The http is off and only httpd24 is running. I moved the zabbix.conf file to the conf.d directory and now I get permission denied.

zabbix.conf file is located in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/`

Any suggestions on how to do this?

OS: RHEL 6.5

```
Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Update: 
I granted access to /usr/share/zabbix in the httpd.conf file and now I can get the login page. However, after login I get a blank page. Viewing source shows no html.

Comment: Please provide current virtualhost configs

Comment: Let me know if this is sufficient

Comment: I granted access to /usr/share/zabbix in the httpd.conf file and now I can get the login page. However, after login I get a blank page. Viewing source shows no html.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_proxy` in apache, and then configure your vhost to proxy requests to `/zabbix` to `http://localhost:81`.

Comment: Updated the original post. I am now getting a permission denied. How can I fix this or try the mod_proxy? Not familiar with it.

Comment: @rheluser99 Research it and give it a try. There are hundreds of posts here on Server Fault about mod_proxy, and countless guides elsewhere.

Comment: Can't seem to find examples with RHEL, only Deb/Ubuntu

Comment: Any guide for CentOS or Fedora would work for you.